# django extending User with UserProfile: User has no userprofile

Tags: django

I have a UserProfile class set up, and I have created a user with user profile via the Django admin console, but I cannot seem to access the userprofile from my view. The error is: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /mcadb/
User has no userprofile. Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?  I've looked at examples and I can't see it. When I load the view, the error seems to be at the test = user.userprofile view. Thank you.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     my_id = models.CharField(max_length=8)
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile

@login_required
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    test = user.userprofile
```

Comment: Try using: `test = user.userprofile_set`

Comment: @Gocht, no, OneToOneField doesn't map to a _set. Besides, it would have been an AttributeError if the name was wrong.

@Carrie, try a bit of debugging. Add `print(user); print UserProfile.objects.all())` above your test line to see on the console if a UserProfile object really exists for this user. If not, try creating a new user & user profile, log in  with the new user and see if the problem exists.

Comment: @gbs, thanks for the suggestions. I'm developing on AWS so I'm not sure if print is supposed to work, but it doesn't seem to. But I can add {{ user.userprofile.my_id }} to my template for the index view, and that does print properly. So the user and user profile exist.

Comment: @gbs, I found the problem. In my actual code (which I had to retype here bc I'm so unfamiliar developing in AWS), I had the import statement for UserProfile before the import statement for User. Switching them seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you very much for helping me get there. :)

Comment: No worries @Carrie, glad to hear you worked it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my actual code (which I had to retype here bc I'm so unfamiliar developing in AWS), I had the import statement for UserProfile before the import statement for User. Switching them, to match what I've posted here, seems to have fixed the problem. So, lesson learned: the order of import statements is important.